# PHP localhost redirected you too many times. CodeIgniter 4 REST API

Tags: php, codeigniter

my index.php in public directory:

```
include(__DIR__ . '/../app/Libraries/checklogin.php');
$operator = $_SESSION['operator_user']; //operator_user is the 
csrf token

include_once(__DIR__ . '/../app/Libraries/config_read.php');

include_once(__DIR__ . '/../app/Language/main.php');

include(__DIR__ . '/../app/Libraries/layout.php');

// print HTML prologue
$title = "Home";

print_html_prologue($title, $langCode);

include(__DIR__ . '/../app/Controllers/menu-home.php');
?>
            <div id="contentnorightbar">
                <h2 id="Intro"><a href="#"></a></h2>
                <p>
<?php 
    include(__DIR__ . '/../app/Libraries/exten- 
welcome_page.php');
?>
                </p>
            </div><!-- #contentnorightbar -->
                    
            <div id="footer">
<?php
$log = "visited page: ";
include(__DIR__ . '/../app/include/config/logging.php');
include(__DIR__ . '/../app/Views/page-footer.php');
?>
            </div><!-- #footer -->
    
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

my checklogin.php at app/Libraries directory:

```
<?php


if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '/Libraries/checklogin.php') 
!== false) {
header("Location: ../index.php");
exit;
}

include('sessions.php');

// start session with timestamp management (1 hour)
dalo_session_start();

// Check if the user is logged in
if (!array_key_exists('daloradius_logged_in', $_SESSION) || 
$_SESSION['daloradius_logged_in'] !== true) {
// If not logged in, set the session variable and redirect to 
login.php
$_SESSION['daloradius_logged_in'] = false;
header('Location: /login.php');
exit;
}

?>
```

my sessions.php at directory: app/Libraries:

```
<?php
// prevent this file to be directly accessed
//if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 
'/../app/Libraries/sessions.php') !== false) {
if (__FILE__ == $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) {
header("Location: ../index.php");
exit;
}

// this function ("installs" and) returns a csrf token
function dalo_csrf_token() {
// Check if PHP supports the random_bytes function
$random = (function_exists('random_bytes'))
    // If supported, generate 32 random bytes
    ? random_bytes(32)
    // If not, use mcrypt_create_iv if available, or 
openssl_random_pseudo_bytes
    : ((function_exists('mcrypt_create_iv')) ? 
mcrypt_create_iv(32, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)
                                             : 
openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));

// Convert the random bytes to a hexadecimal string
$_SESSION['csrf_token'] = bin2hex($random);

// Return the generated CSRF token
return $_SESSION['csrf_token'];
}

// this function can be used for verifying if the csrf token is 
valid
function dalo_check_csrf_token($token) {
// Check if the provided token is empty
if (empty($token)) {
    return false;
}

// Check if hash_equals function is available (for PHP 5.6.0 and 
above)
$result = (function_exists('hash_equals'))
    // If available, use hash_equals to compare tokens
    ? hash_equals($_SESSION['csrf_token'], $token)
    // If not, use simple comparison
    : $_SESSION['csrf_token'] === $token;

// Return the result of token verification (true or false)
return $result;
}


// daloRADIUS session start function support timestamp 
management
function dalo_session_start() {
// maximum life time for session in seconds (1 hour)
$session_max_lifetime = 3600;

// set's the session max lifetime
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', $session_max_lifetime);

// enable strict mode
ini_set('session.use_strict_mode', 1);

// Change PHPSESSID for better security, remove this if set in 
php.ini
session_name('daloradius_sid');

// Secure session_set_cookie_params
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', null, null, true);

// start session if no existing one, resume if got existing one
// based on daloradius_sid (session id)
session_start();

// get current timestamp
$now = time();

// Check if 'time' key exists in the session and is set
if (array_key_exists('time', $_SESSION) && 
isset($_SESSION['time'])) {
    // if too old, destroy and restart (if > 1 hour, destroy & 
restart)
    if ($_SESSION['time'] < $now-$session_max_lifetime) {
        dalo_session_destroy();
        session_start();
        dalo_session_regenerate_id();
    }
} else {
    $_SESSION['time'] = $now;
}

}

// daloRADIUS session regenerate id function
// should be used at least on login and logout
function dalo_session_regenerate_id() {
// Check if a session is not already active
if (session_status() != PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
    session_start();
}

// Generate a new session ID
$session_id = (function_exists('session_create_id'))
    ? session_create_id('daloRADIUS-') : uniqid('daloRADIUS-');

// Update the session time to the current time
$_SESSION['time'] = time();

// Commit and close the current session
session_commit();

// Disable strict mode temporarily
ini_set('session.use_strict_mode', 0);

// Set the new session ID
session_id($session_id);

// Enable strict mode again and start the new session
ini_set('session.use_strict_mode', 1);
session_start();
}

// daloRADIUS session destroy and clean all session variables
function dalo_session_destroy() {
// unset all of the session variables.
$_SESSION = array();

// completely destory the session and all it's variables
session_destroy();
}
```

code snippet of my login.php at directory: app/Controllers

```
<?php

include_once(__DIR__ . '/../Libraries/sessions.php');
dalo_session_start();

if (array_key_exists('daloradius_logged_in', $_SESSION)
&& $_SESSION['daloradius_logged_in'] !== false) {
header('Location: index.php');
exit;
}

// this include "exports" $langCode that can be used later in 
this script
include(__DIR__ . '/../Language/main.php');

// ~ used later for rendering location select element
$onlyDefaultLocation = !(array_key_exists('CONFIG_LOCATIONS', 
$configValues)
                    && 
is_array($configValues['CONFIG_LOCATIONS'])
                    && count($configValues['CONFIG_LOCATIONS']) 
> 0);

?>
```

Lastly, it is my routes.php at app/config directory:

```
<?php

use CodeIgniter\Router\RouteCollection;

/**
 * @var RouteCollection $routes
 */
$routes->resource('User');
//$routes->get('/login.php', 'login');
```

Hopefully someone could help me with my issue: **localhost redirects you too many times**. If there is any more files required for understanding, please do not hesitate to inform me. Thank you so much.

Comment: Welcome to SO, [You should not post code (or errors/exceptions, logs, configuration, project files, or anything else that is represented in textual form) as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2359679), please check this post about how to write a [Minimal & Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)